# Meta Tag are not display on some of pages

Tags: views, meta-tags

I adding meta tag on my site, but some of page showing page title as a Meta title,  I want to change it with other name. 
But I don't know why it is not showing/Working on some of pages .

I observed that some page that connect with View those pages are only fail to add Meta tag.

Anyone know what is issue. Why I'm fail to add meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found reason behind it.

I haven't call `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>`.

After adding it , it is working superb.